# Is a pl/sql refcursor meant to return few records only?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor

I have a query that performs well and is tuned too. I put that in a Procedure. When i execute the query from SQL with a set of values to bind variables used in it the result is produced in 3-4 seconds max.

The same resultset coming from refcursor is taking over 2 minutes to give the result. I understand it is the OPEN FETCH and CLOSE of the cursor that might be taking the time.

I have verified that nothing else in that procedure is consuming the time so that is ruled out.

The number of records returned is around 9000+ which brings me to the question - is a ref cursor somehow less suitable when recordset is of a size that is beyond some limit?

Is the RAM size a problem? I have used TOAD to execute both the query and the procedure to compare. And yes i have gone to the last record, so it is not like the query only returned the first few.

What else can be done to improve this REFCURSOR speed? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing with the results once you've returned them from the procedure, does TOAD display them? If so, is it possible that the problem lies with TOAD being slow at rendering the results of a refcursor?

Comment: @ninesided The procedure is merely displaying the records. TOAD as well as reading in a JDBC both are taking this really long time to print the records. The same query when executed directly (without the procedure) is fast in both TOAD as well as in JDBC.

Comment: have you tried using TKPROF to see where the time is being spent? have you tried running the procedure but NOT rendering the output?

Comment: Show us the procedure !

Answer (score 1):

Are you using BULK COLLECT to grab multiple rows at once?

```
  OPEN c_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_cursor
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab LIMIT 1000; -- or no limit to fetch all at once
    for i in 1 .. l_tab.last loop
      -- process each row
    end loop;
    EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP
  CLOSE c_cursor;
```

Comment: This is a REF CURSOR to a SQL Query that is seen to be really fast when executed in isolation (without the proc ref cursor)

Comment: @user2275460, what I'm suggesting is a way to tune your procedure. Instead of FETCH-ing a single row at a time, you should try using BULK COLLECT to grab a bunch of them (or all) with each fetch.